# How to remove `\n` characters from the end of line?

Tags: perl

[Doc](https://perldoc.pl/functions/chomp) says:

> chomp;  # avoid \n on last field

But when file has windows CRLF, only LF is removed from the end.

```
my $line =  <STDIN>;
print chomp $line;                 # 1
print map{ ord } split '', $line;  # 46 49 13
```

How to remove both `CRLF` characters from the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're having this problem is because Perl's file I/O methods are tuned to work correctly with the line endings used by the local operating system.  When you read a file which uses a different line ending convention (such as a Windows text file being processed under a *nix OS), that can prevent `chomp` from working correctly.

As the first sentence in the perldoc states, `chomp` "*removes any trailing string that corresponds to the current value of `$/`*".  So, if you know when you're using a Windows file vs. when you're using a *nix file, you can work around the different OS line ending convention by setting `$/` accordingly, to `\n` for *nix and to `\r\n` for Windows.

If you don't know which line ending convention a given file uses, then you'll have to fall back on a regex, such as `$line =~ s/\r?\n\z//`.  If removing all trailing whitespace (not just line endings) is acceptable in your situation, `$line =~ s/\s+\z//` will do that for you and potentially save you another step later on.

Comment: Not exactly accurate: the default value of `$/` is always `\n`, but on Windows the default `:crlf` layer will translate `\x0D\x0A` to `\n` on read; on Linux it will not, so you need to handle the Windows line endings yourself if they will be present.

Comment: @ikegami - Edited for `$` => `\z`, but I deliberately chose not to use `\s` here because OP is specifically looking to remove line endings, not all whitespace.

Comment: Also, Grinnz is right. `$/` defaults to `"\n"` on all systems. (Even on the old MacOS systems, though `"\n"` produced a CR rather than a LF there.)

Comment: @ikegami - I've thought things through enough to know that, although removing all trailing whitespace is _usually_ a good thing, it's not _always_ safe to do so (even outside of tab-delimited formats), so I'm not prepared to assume that it's appropriate for the OP. But I did add the `\s+` form as an alternative as you suggested.

Comment: Sadly, that's far from the worst travesty I've encountered in my programming career.  ("OK, here's a COBOL application. Translate it into Visual Basic, and make the VB version behave _exactly the same_." Fifty zillion inert text boxes, followed by a huge OnExit event handler that processes the whole thing when you tab out of the last box...)

Answer (score 4):

Glib answer: Run your program on Windows.

Slightly less glib answer: Run your data file through `dos2unix` before processing it.

Almost entirely not glib answer:

The documentation that you point at starts with this:

> This safer version of chop removes any trailing string that corresponds to the current value of `$/`

So if you want to change the behaviour of `chomp()` you need to change the value of `$/`.

```
{ # Always localise changes to Perl's internal variables.

  local $/ = "\015\012";

  chomp; # Now removes Windows line endings

} # Revert $/ to original value
```